# Binding to a value within a Resource?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Assuming one has this Resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ImageBrush x:Key="MyImageBrush" Opacity="0.5"
             ImageSource="image1.png" Stretch="None" 
             AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then how would I get to the Opacity value of that resource?
I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyImageBrush, Path=Opacity}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyImageBrush}, Path=Opacity}" />
```